# snake plant young leaf tip broken

Tags: indoors, succulents

A young leaf of a snake plant's tip at the top of the leaf broke off.

will it continue to grow, or just not grow at all?

Answer (score 2):

The tip will not grow back.  However the leaf will continue to grow if light and nutrients are available.

Plants are different than people in the way they deal with injuries.  Plants will wall off the injured zone and carry on.  Trees take it one step further. They wall off the injury and attempt to grow over it.

Comment: thanks, i read somewhere that once tip brakes off, the leaf will nolonger grow anymore. thanks now i feel better, knowing my plant will continue to grow.

Comment: Well your plant will continue to grow, but yes, that leaf may not get any taller than it is now - its one of the foibles of this particular plant, but if its just a tiny bit  at the tip, it might still grow taller anyway. Other leaves will arise from the base anyway, over time.